# My answer got converted to Community Wiki

Tags: support, specific-question, community-wiki, user-accounts

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183669/difference-between-join-and-outer-join-in-mysql/3183687#3183687) was converted to Community Wiki. Can someone give me an explanation for this?

Comment: Don't bump it that much and it won't happen.

Comment: @Georg - true, such kind of editing really looks like "oh, I can earn more reputation with that, let's show it more!".

Comment: yes thats true but i dont have info about this ... but i must say thank you and sorry for that .. will not going to do it again

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because you edited your answer more than 8 times. According to the revision history, which is the link just above your name, at the bottom-right corner of your answer, you edited it 12 times.

Note that [this feature has since been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism/228940#228940) and editing a question or an answer can no longer convert it to Community Wiki. For more in-depth information about the Community Wiki feature, please see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: `# The post has been edited eight (8) times by the original owner.` 12 > 8

Comment: (no +1 because you could really have cited that one line Farseeker did cite...)

Comment: (-1) RTFM is not appropriate for StackOverflow

Comment: @pranay: sorry, i didn't mean for this to be an rtfm. i just got done asking the very question about quoting answers elsewhere and i thought that including a simple link to the rules was the most informative. answering at 1am when i'm half asleep didn't help. :-P

Comment: updated with what i meant to say, before i made the terse right-before-bed posting. :-P

Comment: In retrospect, with all kind of rules changing over time, I actually *do* think linking to the FAQ is better.

Comment: This answer is out of date, again, so I just flagged the question as a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/130885

Comment: No wonder many highly voted answers are cw on stackoverflow. I always had thought some users here really dont care about rep and they just graciously and willingly make it cw.. Now I know its not :)

Comment: My answer never edited, not even once. But still made as cw by an editor, and now I'm not gaining reputation for that. I would vote for stopping "converting to community wiki"