# I've accidently made an answer community wiki. How can I undo this?

Tags: support, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [12 edits make an answer community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84424/12-edits-make-an-answer-community-wiki)
>   [Is there a way to remove community wiki status?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status)

I added [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451593/4-points-and-ellipse/5460918#5460918) and edited it to correct a mistake and add more information. It was made community wiki after 12 edits, but it is a regular answer. How can I undo this?

Comment: Community wikis are one way

Comment: One a question is made community wiki (in this cause, caused by a large number of edits) as far as I know it can't be reverted.

Comment: but it strange that if i add new information in my answer several times and do it more full. and now i don't get reputetion for this answer...

Comment: @Sonorx, if you read the possible dupe you will see an explanation. The goal is to stop you making trivial edits for the purpose of bumping up your answer and getting more upvotes.

Comment: I don't know it. And if don't edit it answer wasn't full. But man who ask want full answer, isn't it?

Comment: He asked me to do some edits. and also i correct mistake in answer.

Comment: And, the gaming @Belinda mentioned, is known [to have happened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57971/my-answer-got-converted-to-community-wiki).

Comment: I noticed you added a comment to your answer. Note that a comment is not the same as clicking the "flag" link!

Comment: I add that comment in flag link, and duplicate it in comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag to moderator attention and write your comments accordingly so that mods can change

Comment: Thanks thats works for me) i think because my edit was not small or empty)

Answer (score -2):

I think you can still Delete a CW answer (if it is yours). So you could Copy-Paste it to a new answer and delete the old one. You can't take the points with you.

Comment: points on deleted posts are only stay until recalc

Comment: Somehow this feels messy. Note that 10k users will then see both the deleted answer and the new one. Just for some reputation?

Comment: No, this is the wrong way.