# Can a user revert Community Wiki on a post?

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki

Suppose that a Stack Overflow user answered a question and he marked it as Community Wiki. If no other user modifies the post, then the current version is exactly the same as it was originally written.

In this case, can the user change the Community Wiki designation and gain back the reputation they deserve?

Comment: What would prevent people from always doing this to "test the waters" so that they don't lose their reputation?

Comment: Are you asking if this is possible, or requesting that this be changed?  The wording, and also the tagging, makes it ambiguous to me.

Comment: When you post an answer in StackOverflow you mark a checkbox that said if it is Community Wiki. The question is that if you can change that selection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I've accidently made an answer community wiki. How can I undo this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85456/ive-accidently-made-an-answer-community-wiki-how-can-i-undo-this)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Users can't, but Diamond moderators can remove the Community Wiki designation from posts.

If you feel a post was marked Community Wiki but shouldn't be, flag it for their attention, explaining why you think the Community Wiki designation is incorrect.

Comment: How can the user flag for the Diamond attention?

Comment: @RaulOtaño [Click the "flag" link under the post.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#flagging)