# Answered as comunity wiki, now how to revert it?

Tags: feature-request, answers, community-wiki

I have answered a question on stackoverflow with status of **community wiki**. Now I want to revert it as a user.

Is there any way to revert this answer to **non-community wiki** status ?

Comment: no, there is no such checkbox.

Comment: @Aziz only a moderator can "unwikify" posts.

Comment: Also closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152717/can-a-user-revert-community-wiki-on-a-post.