# See which posts had their CW status removed

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, community-wiki

According to this thread, 
[Can a user revert Community Wiki on a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152717/413396), diamond moderators can remove the community wiki status from a post.

Is there any way to know from which posts community wiki status has been removed, e.g. using data explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no direct event recorded in PostHistory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) but you can indirectly find those posts.

The PostHistory table has rows with PostHistoryTypeid = 16 for posts that were made communitywiki. The Posts table has the field CommunityOwnedDate. If a post has row in its Posthistory for typeid = 16 but has an empty CommunityOwnedDate field then that post had its status removed. The only thing we can't know is when that happened.

Here is the [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/947111):

```
select distinct 
       ph.postid as [Post Link]
     , p.posttypeid
from posthistory ph
inner join posts p on p.id = ph.postid
where posthistorytypeid = 16  -- Community Wiki
and p.communityowneddate is null -- Non CW status
```

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday morning. Don't forget to checkout the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) and say "Hi" in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).